# Receive locale notification on watch while iOS is in foreground

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, watchkit, apple-watch, foreground

Is there any way to receive local notifications on the watch while the parent iOS app is still in foreground? For example, press a button on the phone and get the notification on the watch (while the watch is inactive).

This is **NOT** working (on iOS side):

```
let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertBody = "Local notifications are working"
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotification)
```

Comment: If your iOS app supports local or remote notifications, Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times.

iOS it self decide to pass the notification to Apple Watch or show on iPhone,

As you said the implementation is done so let the iOS handle it. and at this time you have to do nothing to pass it to Watch you can see the Apple documentation for more clarification.

Comment: so if the phone is active, the iPhone will decide to show the notification on the phone and I will never even receive the notification on the watch because it is only shown **EITHER** on phone **OR** watch.. so there is no way with an active ios app?